# sorting objects by attribute in an array within a class which are themselves objects of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects which are stored within another object and then display the sorted objects. I want to sort these objects by a specific attribute. I'm not exactly sure how I am supposed to run the sort() method.

composer.h

```
class Composer {
  Public:
    int get_ranking();
    ..
    ..
};
```

database.h

```
Class Database {
  Public:
    void DisplayAll(){
      for(int i=0;i<next_slot_;i++){
            composers_[i].Display();
      }
    };

    bool SortByRank(Composer const & a, Composer const & b) {
        return a.get_ranking() < b.get_ranking();
    };

    void DisplayByRank(){
      sort(composers_, composers_+next_slot_, SortByRank);
      DisplayAll();
    };
```

testdatabase.cpp

```
int main(){
  Database myDB;

  Composer& comp1 = myDB.AddComposer("Ludwig van", "Beethoven", "Romantic", 1770,
                   "Beethoven was completely deaf during the latter part of his life - he 
                    never heard a performance of his 9th symphony.");
  comp1.Promote(7);

  Composer& comp2 = myDB.AddComposer("Johann Sebastian", "Bach", "Baroque", 1685,
                   "Bach had 20 children, several of whom became famous musicians as well.");
  comp2.Promote(5);

  cout << endl << "all Composers: " << endl << endl;
  myDB.DisplayAll();
  myDB.DisplayByRank();
```

When I run this I get:

> error: passing 'const Composer' as 'this' argument of 'int Composer::get_ranking()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] return a.get_ranking() < b.get_ranking();

and

> error: no matching function for call to 'sort(Composer [100], Composer*, unresolved overloaded function type)'
>      sort(composers_, composers_+next_slot_, SortByRank);

Adding const to the end of get_ranking() seems to have solved the const correctness error.

Comment: In `SortByRank`, `Composer` is const, `get_ranking()` is not. BOOM.

Comment: Did you really get an error message with the substring "and error:", or is that two separate error messages that you concatenated with the word "and" (rather than a line break) between them?

Comment: You really have to practice reading C++ errors: `error: passing 'const Composer' as 'this' argument of 'int Composer::get_ranking()' discards qualifiers`, i.e., your method is not const-correct.

Comment: So I believe i corrected the const correctness by making get_ranking() const as recommended by @bartop. Now I'm just getting:    `error: no matching function for call to 'sort(Composer[100], Composer*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'`  This is a learning process for me so I am no expert, but what i think is going on is that i am incorrectly calling the composer class method in SortByRank(). I'm just not exactly sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try changing your sort statement to this :: `sort(composers_, composers_+next_slot_, &SortByRank);`

Comment: Changing to &SortByRank returns: `error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Database::SortByRank' [-fpermissive]`  and also: `error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* __comp) (...)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I did a fair amount of reading and learned a bit.

After resolving my const correctness by changing `int get_ranking();` to `int get_ranking()const` it turned out my SortByRank() still wasn't working. This was because it was a non-static member of Database requiring a `this` pointer. Simply changing it to: `static bool SortByRank();` or defining SortByRank() outside of the Database class solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `const` to `get_ranking` method.

```
class Composer {
public:
    int get_ranking() const;
};
```

Which is part of C++ const-correctness. It means that the method does not change internal state of the object (except `mutable` fields which are rather rarely used) it is called by and allows to call this method by `const` objects.